# How much time is an iOS app given when unsuspended or relaunched by a background service?

Tags: ios, background, geolocation

I have a location-based iOS 4 app that relies on significant location change monitoring while in the background. Apple's docs state:

> At wake-up time, your application is
>   put into the background and given a
>   small amount of time to process the
>   location data. Because your
>   application is in the background, it
>   should do minimal work and avoid any
>   tasks (such as querying the network)
>   that might prevent it from returning
>   before the allocated time expires.

Does anyone know how long "a small amount of time is?" Specifically, I'm wondering if I have enough time to call `startUpdatingLocation` on a location manager in order to get a more accurate fix than what might be provided by the initial location event. (My background location events almost always report their `horizontalAccuracy` as 1000m.)

If Apple's "small amount of time" would be insufficient for that purpose, am I allowed to call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` from a backgrounded application in order to request more time? I know that usually gives you an additional 600s, which is more than adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely need to find a more accurate fix during application re-launch, or can you do this heavy lifting after your app has been moved into the foreground, and show a "Loading..." type screen while the work happens? That would eliminate any concerns regarding timeouts.

Comment: At wake/relaunch, I'm trying to determine if the user is within range of some predefined locations. If not, it should go back to sleep until it receives another location event. Region-based monitoring would be a better logical fit, but this is essentially a novelty app and I don't want the battery hit of always-on monitoring.